# mod_rewrite apache2.4 rule not working

Tags: apache-http-server, mod-rewrite

I am trying to configure .htaccess for a very simple URL redirect with Apache 2.4

From: /order/step1.php?service=151
To: /order/step-1/151

My .htaccess is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?/([^/d]+)/?$ /order/step1.php?service=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I am sure I am missing something wacky, does anyone know what I am doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern will not match the given "From" text.

You are currently matching:

```
^ beginning of the text
/? an optional slash
/ a slash
([^/d]+) a sequence of 1 or more characters not matching a slash and the letter "d" (and capture this text)
/? an optional slash
$ end of the text
```

You need to match:

```
^ beginning of the text
/order/ this literal text
([^0-9-]+) match all characters except digits and a dash, and capture this
- a dash
([0-9]+) match all digits and capture this
\.php\?service= match ".php?service="
([0-9]+) match all digits and capture this
```

You can then use these captured strings to build the replacement:

```
/order/$1-$2/$3
```

So the final RewriteRule line is:

```
RewriteRule ^/order/([^0-9-]+)-([0-9]+)\.php\?service=([0-9]+)$ /order/$1-$2/$3 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: So if I only want it to work with step1.php and not all steps, would it just be this? RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/order/step1\.php\?service=([0-9]+)$ /order/step1/$1 [L,QSA]

Comment: That is correct. BTW I would expect the rewrite to go the other way: the user enters a simpler URL http://host/order/step1/123 and that would be rewritten to send the request to /order/step1.php?service=123, but if you want the use to use the php link then it's correct as is

Comment: Well, we're converting the site to laravel and the old site uses step1.php?service=1 where as the new site uses step1/1 so we need to redirect the old links to the new format so that all of our old links don't 404

Comment: Oh, it's not working because the rewrite for laravel rewrites all of the URLs, that's unfortunate I am going to have to figure out how to have it not do that.